# Sigmoid function with parameter that controls length of approximate linearity

Tags: sigmoid-curve

It is well known that many sigmoid functions are approximately linear around x=0. I am looking for a sigmoid function that has a parameter that controls the length of this segment. I want to measure the length of this segment by its projection onto the y axis. Edit: The sigmoid function should map to the interval [-1, 1] on the y axis, so it is about which portion of this is linear. Additionally, the gradient at 0 should be 1.

In this image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function#/media/File:Gjl-t(x).svg) I would consider erf as the most linear and x / (1 + |x|) the least linear: [image]

In the extreme linearity case I want the function to converge to being -1 for x<=1, x for -1<x<1 and 1 for x>1.

Comment: Just multiply its values by desired length: that scales everything on the y axis.  But what would the potential statistical application of this be?

Comment: @whuber Sorry, my question was unclear so I have updated it. I actually want to keep the output interval fixed. My statistical application is using the inverse as a warping function for a Warped Gaussian Process. But I agree that it is not inherently a statistics question. Are you aware of another StackExchange forum where I could ask it?

Comment: What is your purpose? You can make the sigmoid so steep that the middle section is nearly vertical--it'd de quite useless but "straight".

Comment: @Tim Okay, I also want to normalize the gradient at 0 to 1

Comment: @Tim In the extreme case I want the sigmoid to be basically x from -0.99 to 0.99 and then have a vary fast falloff in function change for any values outside that range

Comment: What do you need it for? Why do you need it linear? What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve? There is no strict definition of "sigmoid function" so you could create arbitrary functions that meet the conditions and are S-shaped.

Comment: @Tim I have basically evaluated the perfect warping function by using a lot of samples and estimating the CDF of my original distribution and now try to find a function family to match them with as few parameters as possible.

Comment: @Tim I have observed that they mainly vary as visualized in the image that I have now added in my question but tend to have a much longer linear segment in some cases.

Comment: Why not just use a linear function truncated at bounds?

Comment: Any sigmoid function $\sigma(x)$ can be re-expressed as $\sigma(ax + b)$ for $a \neq 0$. So if you're not asking about how to adjust $a$, I'm not sure what you're asking. And likewise, you can scale and shift the output, if desired: $c\sigma(ax +b)+d$. If this isn't flexible enough, you need to explain how & why in detail.

Comment: @Tim Because that's not what the functions I want to model look like. I need to be able to smoothly interpolate between normal curvy sigmoid function like the Gaussian inverse CDF and the piecewise linear one.

Comment: @Sycorax I'm referring to the more general definition of Sigmoid functions from the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function So basically any inverse CDF of a continuous distribution is a sigmoid function if you scale and shift it.

Comment: Neglecting that I think you mean "CDF" instead of "inverse CDF", this does not appear to conflict with anything in your post or that I’ve written.

Comment: I mean CDF not inverse CDF

Comment: @Jannis it is *not* true that any inverse CDF is a sigmoid.